# Python - Making For loops to 1x1 degree grids Only for seas

Tags: python, for-loop, coordinates

I would like to do some meteorological calculation in the sea area. What I'm trying to do is making calculation for every 1x1 degree grid cells. like,

Go to the grid (to start somewhere with coordinates)

Make Calculations.

Go to another grid

Make calculations..

so on...

I made it with square but it doesn't help me to skip land areas.

I would like to make only for seas. when the coordinate falls on the land areas it has to skip (I don't know how). and move on to the next grid.

I can appreciate any tips from you guys.

[image: an example]

edit : Is there a any possibility to determining all the coordinates and make with them a database or some kind of lists. and when the calculation begins the code runs for loop only in the list? honestly I don't know do it as well.

Sorry for mentioning the data. I've downloaded ECMWF's meteorological data model called ERA5 and the data looks like this.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMrkS.png)

The code below is my first trial actually its working for a square

latt = [48,49,50,51]
lonn = [38,39,40,41]

for the information this list in this code represents a 4x4 matrix the numbers inside doesn't mean anything actually.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from windrose import WindroseAxes
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import timeit
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl

data = pd.read_csv("/opt/local/var/macports/software/A.xlsx", index_col=0, parse_dates=True, header=None)
df = data.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={0:"Date", 1:"Lon", 2:"Lat", 3:"Value"}, inplace=True)
df["Value"] = (df["Value"]-273.14)

#Coordinate starting points.
n = 48
y = 49
z = 38
t = 39

#aylar
aylar = ["OCAK","ŞUBAT","MART","NİSAN","MAYIS","HAZİRAN","TEMMUZ","AĞUSTOS","EYLÜL","EKİM","KASIM","ARALIK"]
kaylar = ["oca","sub","mar","nis","may","haz","tem","agu","eyl","eki","kas","ara"]
ay = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
loop = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"]

mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000

latt = [48,49,50,51]
lonn = [38,39,40,41]
j=ay[0]

for h in range(len(latt)):
    for g in range(len(lonn)):
        #This is where i filter my first grid (A1)
        s = df[(df['Lat'] >= n) & (df['Lat'] <= y)]
        s = s[(s['Lon'] >= z) & (s['Lon'] <= t)]
        
        m = 0
        x = 1
        r = kaylar[m]
        p = aylar[m]
        
        for i in range(len(loop)):
            
            #plots#
            
            plt.savefig("/Users/muratoksuz/Desktop/URUN/KAR/"+str(r)+"/K{j}/sic/K{j}_sicaklik.jpeg".format(j=j),dpi=500, bbox_inches="tight")
            m += 1
            x += 1
            
        j += 1
        
        n += 1
        y += 1
        
    z += 1
    t += 1
    n = 48
    y = 49
```

That code starts from given coordinates and make a calculation for whole months and saves figures to different folders in my pc. and goes to the another grid to do same calculation for that grid. K or A is just a name for grids.

[This is the folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmb7Y.png)

And this is the wished result.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CSfs.jpg)

Comment: I'm confused. Are those grids composed out of satellite images?

Comment: Can you share what your input data looks like, or what you're using as a data source? The pictures and problem description are very clear, but the answer depends quite a bit on your data format.

Comment: I updated the post sorry for forgetting the data type. its just a Dataframe with includes lat lon date and value columns.

Comment: @MuratÖksüz thanks for the update. Can you distinguish land from sea cells from `value` column or isn't any actual information on that? If not, there's not much to do here except from finding another database that includes this info and cross check via latitude/longitude or (even worse) build an sea/not sea image classifier (e.g. CNN) from scratch and use it with satellite images.

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I cannot distinguish values cause for example the wind data blows everywhere. Well what im thinking is maybe I can determine the grids before my calculation. for example K1 falls between Lat :51 lat:52 and lon:33 lon:34 and determine other cells like this. and run a loop for all of them. but determining like more than 70 grid like this is kind a not feels right I want to do things automatic but idk I guess I need to find a database like you mentioned...